# Neon toolkit and Gate Web Service

Tags: web-services, ontology, neon

I am trying to run any of the services from gate web service, in neon 2.3.

Even Annie that runs so well in gate doesn't run, or better, it stay for indefinite time processing, a thing that should take no more than a couple of seconds. I run wizard, set input directory, leave file pattern as default and set a folder and name for the output ontology, shouldn't it be enough? Shouldn't i get something, even an error?

I think its the location who's giving me problems.

http://safekeeper1.dcs.shef.ac.uk/neon/services/sardine

http://safekeeper1.dcs.shef.ac.uk/neon/services/sprat

http://safekeeper1.dcs.shef.ac.uk/neon/services/annie

http://safekeeper1.dcs.shef.ac.uk/neon/services/termraider

How can i confirm it?  Can i run it offline?

Can anyone give me a hand?

Also, i've seen sprat running on gate, on "SPRAT: a tool for automatic semantic pattern-based ontology population"

Can anyone teach me how, and with what versions?

Thx,

[Celso Costa](http://whatisprymas.wordpress.com/)